# Accessing contact data Android

Tags: android, contacts

If I'm assigning a value to a field of a contact, such as nickname;

```
.withValue(Nickname.NAME, "Mr. Incredible")
```

it is stored in the DATA1 column according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.html

Yet, if I add a SIP Address with SipAddress.SIP_ADDRESS() it's value is also assigned to column DATA1. How do I differentiate between these two? I'm a bit confused on how to access a contacts specific fields and I can't find an explanation in the Android Reference.

I'm specifically using

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                        R.layout.contact_list, null, new String[] {
                        SipAddress.DISPLAY_NAME, SipAddress.SIP_ADDRESS, Nickname.NAME},
                        new int[] {
                        R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3}, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try,

```
try {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME},
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.DATA1 + "=" + text, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String Nickname = cursor.getString(0);
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this problem: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getContentResolver() from the type ContextWrapper

Comment: Also, what is the 'text' variable

Comment: you'll need to pass a Context into your static method

Comment: ok so cursor.getString(0) only gets one Nickname value. It's not recognizing it as a column

Comment: Oli, can you help me with this one? It is similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636297/display-correct-values-with-cursorloader-adapter-android

Answer (score 0):

Yes its saved in `ContactsContract.DataColumns.DATA1`   with the String `SIP_ADDRESS`. May this helps you [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.SipAddress](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.SipAddress.html)

Happy coding!

Comment: Both Nickname and SIP address are in DATA1? How do I access them separately? Suppose I wanted just the nicknames.

Comment: ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.SipAddress.MIMETYPE/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.NAME ? :)

Comment: They both still return 'data1' :(

Comment: `android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"` is set?

Comment: if you check [DEV](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.SipAddress.html#SIP_ADDRESS) the  Constant Value is "data1"